# Email_cron:The following tag has a syntax error: {exp:cron}

Tags: cron, expressionengine

I have installed cron_email addon but get this error message in the template

```
Error

The following tag has a syntax error:

{exp:cron}

Please correct the syntax in your template.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified on the [Cron Send Email page](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/cron_send_email), "Requirements: ExpressionEngine Cron plugin". So make sure it is installed as well: http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/expressionengine_cron